# modeling spatial distribution of trajectory intensity in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I have x,y,z coordinates for the trajectory of a moving object at equal time intervals together with the intensity (expressed as kinetic energy `Etot`):

```
      t        x      y        z     Etot
1  0.00 696621.4 167730 1680.960 1192.526
2  0.01 696621.4 167730 1680.959 1192.526
3  0.02 696621.4 167730 1680.958 1192.526
4  0.04 696621.4 167730 1680.952 1192.526
5  0.06 696621.4 167730 1680.942 1192.526
6  0.08 696621.4 167730 1680.929 1192.526
7  0.11 696621.4 167730 1680.901 1192.526
8  0.13 696621.4 167730 1680.877 1192.526
9  0.15 696621.4 167730 1680.850 1192.526
10 0.16 696621.4 167730 1680.834 1192.526
```

I want to create a raster file that indicated the probability of each cell that the object will pass thought the cell and with what kinetic energy.

The purpose of this is that in the future I will have many trajectories and will be using this procedure to create a spatial distribution of trajectory intensity.

For now I have created a raster .tiff file:

```
colnames(df) <- c("t", "x", "y", "z", "Etot")
head(df,10)
df$trajectory <- 1

library(raster)
library(sp)

# create a SpatialPointsDataFrame
coordinates(df) <- ~ x+y

# create an empty raster object to the extent of the points
rast <- raster(ext=extent(df), resolution=2)

# rasterize your irregular points 
rasOut<-rasterize(df, rast, df$z, fun = mean)

fout="my_raster.tif"
writeRaster(rasOut, fout, format="GTiff", overwrite = T)
```

However this creates a non smooth trajectory and does not indicate the kinetic energy of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some data in a reproducible example

```
df <- read.table(text="t        x      y        z     Etot
1  0.00 696621.4 167730 1960 11.92
2  0.01 696621.4 167720 1959 11.92
3  0.02 696631.4 167730 1958 119.2
4  0.04 696631.4 167740 1952 1192
5  0.06 696641.4 167730 1942 11.92
6  0.08 696641.4 167720 1929 119.2
7  0.11 696651.4 167740 1901 11.92
8  0.13 696651.4 167720 1877 1192
9  0.15 696661.4 167730 1850 1192
10 0.16 696661.4 167740 1834 1192")
df$trajectory <- 1
```

Your code, slightly condensed

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ext=extent(df[, c('x', 'y')]), resolution=2)
r <- rasterize(df[, c('x', 'y')], r, df$Etot, fun = mean)
plot(r)
```

This seems to work. The only important difference with your code is that you were rasterizing `df$z` instead of `df$Etot`.